# Palindrome program produces incorrect output

Tags: c++, palindrome

I'm trying a problem on [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl/) ("Sphere Online Judge", a programming puzzle site), where I need to generate the smallest palindrome larger than the given number. I tried to solve it by calculating two sides of palindrome with modulo and int division, but it still gives me the wrong answer. What can be the problem?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int inverse(int a){
    int inv = 0;
    while( a > 0){
        inv = inv*10 + a%10;
        a = a/10;
    } // while
    return inv;
} // inverse

int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        int size  = 0;
        int tmp = a;
        while(tmp > 0){
            size++;
            tmp/=10;
        } // while

        bool even = false;
        int middle = size/2;
        if(size%2==0)even = true;
        if(!even)middle++;
        int l = a/pow(10.0,size-middle);
        int r = a%int(pow(10.0,middle));
        int lr = inverse(l);
        if(lr <= r){
            l++;
            lr=inverse(l);
        } // if

        if(!even)
            lr%=int(pow(10.0,middle-1));

        int wynik = l*pow(10.0,size-middle)+lr;

        if(a==9)
            wynik=11;
        else if(a==0)
            wynik = 1;

        cout << wynik << endl;
    } // for

    return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: What is SPOJ? more characters

Comment: @Almo: [tag:spoj]: *"The Sphere Online Judge (http://www.spoj.pl/) is a site with a collection of programming problems of varying difficulty.*"

Comment: What input did you give it, what output did you expect, and what output did you actually receive?

Comment: @Kevin: Actually, for every input i give(ex: 112, 99), result is ok(121, 101), but when I submit it to SPOJ,it tells "Wrong Answer", so there must be a case for which my program returns wrong output.

Comment: I tested your algorithm against my own implementation, and the results are the same up to 1,000,000. So I think your math is sound but you're somehow printing it wrong. Maybe you shouldn't print an `endl` after the last output?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that by calculations. My output is good, but I have read about input again, and found out that input number can have 1,000,000 digits, so I have to solve this problem with strings. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: How are you gonna handle a integer with 1 mil digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [problem description](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PALIN/), you have to be able to handle positive integers of any size less than one million digits. Your implementation is based on the `int` type, so it can only handle numbers up to around nine digits long (give or take a few digits depending on your system's INT_MAX).

Sample input:

```
1
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Sample output:

```
-2147483648
```

Your output is incorrect. The correct output is `100000000000000000000000000000000000000001`.